# How can I make this code fetch the data from Firebase automatically (without pressing the Floating Action Button)? I am new to Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch data from Realtime DB which I am uploading through my ESP32. I can fetch the data by pressing the Floating Action Button but I want this to work automatically, whenever the data changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

[I can fetch the data by pressing the Floating Action Button. I want this to update the data whenever the data changes in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0EeC.png)

```
 void initState() {
    _getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _getData() {
    ref.once().then((DataSnapshot data) {
      print(data.value);
      setState(() {
        temperature = data.value["temperature"];
        spo2 = data.value["SPO2"];
        heartRate = data.value["BPM"];
      });
    });
  }
.
. 
.

floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          onPressed: () {
            _getData();
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Use `StreamBuilder` and provide your firebase data as stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flutter way of doing this is using a StreamBuilder, straight from the cloud_firestore Dart pub page:
Look at this sample code to get inspiration

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('naruto').snapshots(),
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
   if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
     return   
       // Your code comes here

    );
  },
 );
```

Comment: thanks for the response.. this code is related to Firestore. I am using FirebaseDatabase and i dont know how to implement that under a streambuilder

Comment: Read this article for some inspiration. https://medium.com/codechai/realtime-database-in-flutter-bef0f29e3378

Answer (score 2):

You can use StreamBuilder for this. StreamBuilder widget is mainly made for this only.
It takes mainly 2 parameters, first is stream and other is builder. StreamBuilder listens for the change in stream and builder builds your UI then.

Comment: thank you so much for the response sir! can I have some example code on it? I can find many code related to firestone but none on the Realtime database. any help would be appreciated :)